# I need an output :not("a") inside the li tags

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="header">
    <li class="header-text">Head1</li>
    <li class="header-text"><a href="#">line11</a></li>
    <li class="header-text"><a href="#">line12</a></li>
    <li class="header-text"><a href="#">line13</a></li>
    <li class="header-text"><a href="#">line14</a></li>
    <li class="header-text"><a href="#">line15</a></li>
<ul>
<ul class="header">
    <li class="header-text">Head2</li>
    <li class="header-text"><a href="#">line21</a></li>
    <li class="header-text"><a href="#">line22</a></li>
    <li class="header-text"><a href="#">line23</a></li>
    <li class="header-text"><a href="#">line24</a></li>
    <li class="header-text"><a href="#">line25</a></li>
<ul>
```

On Clicking the "ul" i need the output as "Head1" or "Head2" and nothing else

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far. And as you can see on the variety of answers you got, you should probably clarify what you mean by *"i need the output as "Head1" or "Head2" and nothing else"*. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can use some css like below,

    .header-text a {
        display: none;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple using `.closest()` and `:eq()` 
  http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/ 
 http://api.jquery.com/closest/

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/apepah/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('.header li a').click(function( e ) {

  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default browser action on anchors
  var desiredText = $(this).closest('.header').find('li:eq(0)').text();
  alert( desiredText );

} );
```

Comment: I need the output on clicking the anchor tags and not for the whole UL....sorry for the miscommunication

Answer (score 2):

If i am not wrong you want `li` which do not have `a` child.

So use `:not` and `:has`

```
$('li:not(:has(a))')
```

**For `UL` click**

```
$('ul').on('click',function(){
   var li_wihtout_a = $(this).find('li:not(:has(a))');
   console.log(li_wihtout_a);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I guess there is some syntax error in this

Comment: I need the output on clicking the anchor tags and not for the whole UL....sorry for the miscommunication

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy if you just want to get the first child's text.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E5wj5/1/)

**JS**

```
$('.header').click(function () {
    alert(this.children[0].innerHTML);
});
```

I also noticed that you have not closed your `<ul>` tags correctly.

Comment: Sine closing `ul` tags are optional, the HTML is still valid though (even if it is not what was intended).

Comment: @FelixKling is closing ul tags optional? Plus he's opening them twice, rather than not just closing them.

Comment: @chim: Ha, I looked at the wrong paragraph. They are *not* optional, closing `li` tags are optional. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2

Comment: Optional but highly recommended.

Comment: It actually changes the meaning of a lot for this example and is invalid (you have a ul in a ul in a u, uls can only contain lil).

Answer (score 0):

If your markup is consistent and as above then use the :first selector